# swift change SKSpriteNode image in SKScene class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I defined SKSpriteNode under SKScene class, how can i change the SKSpriteNode image afterwards, for example:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
}
```

I want to change the image from "player" to "player1" during some action. I do not inherit SKNode class, so i can not use SKTexture method to do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`SKScene` is a subclass of `SKNode` so you do in fact inherit it. You can use `SKTexture` to change the image like this:

```
player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player1")
```